# If you had no installed any packages via pip yet, what packages should be listed by running pip list?

Tags: python, pip

Context is I accidentally installed some packages to my global python environment and am not which are safe to uninstall.

Comment: Try creating a new python virtual environment and then do `pip list` to see what packages come up

Comment: why dont you try to uninstall pip and reinstall it ?

Comment: @manaclan Uninstall pip?

Comment: Very much depends on OS and package manager. If you've installed Python and pip on Linux using distribution's package manager it probably installed a lot of it's own modules which you must not uninstall or the package manager stops working.

Answer (score 0):

Clean installation has the following packages:

```
Package    Version
---------- -------
pip        19.3.1 
setuptools 41.6.0
```